# I want to send a json data using by submit button without jquery ajax

Tags: jquery

I want to send a  JSON data using by submit button.

before, I worked like this ...

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){     
    $('form[name="boardForm"]').attr('value',"[name:'john']");              
    $('form[name="boardForm"]').attr('action',"/test/result");
    $('form[name="boardForm"]').submit();
});
```

but, this is not working in php code.

I want to send a json data using jquery submit without jquery ajax.

hot to get result code?

Comment: form does not have a value attribute, you need to have a input fields to send data to server

Comment: Why don't you want to use AJAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should have a input field(hidden) and set the value of the input field instead of form

Ex

```
<form name="boardForm">
    <input name="json" type="hidden"/>
    ....
</form>
```

JS

```
$("#btn_submit").click(function(){
    var form = $('form[name="boardForm"] input[name="json"]').val("{name:'john'}");
    form.attr('action',"/test/result"); 
    form.submit(); 
});
```

Comment: Is there any other way without <input type="hidden"> field?

Comment: Do you want the json sent as request body not as request parameter?